# Instant Run - It keeps saying a class has been added when there is none

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I've updated my Android Studio setup to `2.0-beta2` release in order to have a taste on the new Instant Run feature.

I've followed all instructions available including updating Gradle plugin to `2.0.0-beta2` and such but alas, I still can't get IR to run.

[image]

That message appears all the time I want to run my app using IR. The main caveat here that I did not add any new class to my code base; not even one. All I did before running that build was changing 2 lines within one of my custom `View` class from this:

```
    subView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    subView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

..to this:

```
    subView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    subView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Despite that fact I still can't get IR to run.

Any clues on what's happening here?

Comment: It does not seem you have changed anything, both snippets look the same. Could you please check that?

Comment: Sorry my bad, please check the updated question.